# How can I change the Datastore of a Published Layer in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, data-source

I have Published a Layer on Geoserver using Shapefile as the datastore. This data has now been stored in a PostGIS database as a Spatial Table. This PostGIS database has been added a new DataSource.

Is it possible to just change the DataStore of a published layer, so that it will now point to this new DataSource? This will avoid having to set all the setting once again.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to do so via the user interface, but you should be able to do it via PUT requests against the FeatureType objects, using the REST API, and changing the link from the old datastore to the new datastore.
See the documentation here and try some requests against your local GeoServer, GET the xml description and PUT back a modified one pointing to the other store:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html